# How can I apply STUFF() to comma from three table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables

Employee:

```
  emp_id    email_addr
    1   aaaa@gmail.com
    2   bbbb@gmail.com
    3   cccc@gmail.com
    4   dddd@gmail.com
    5       eeee@gmail.com
```

Users:

```
  usr_id    ishod   areaid  emp_id
    1   0   1   1
    2   1   2   2
    3   0   3   3
    4   0   1   4
    5   1   2   5
    6   1   5   6
```

Device:

```
   id   areaname
    1   DXB
    2   MAA
    3   TRV
```

if i have same area for two or more employee i need to separete email column with comma

```
   SELECT u.emp_id,
   stuff ((SELECT ', ' + email_addr
   FROM  users u
   FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') email
   FROM users u left join  employee SS on u.emp_id=ss.emp_id
   where u.ishod=1
   GROUP  BY u.emp_id,u.areaid,ss.email_addr
```

I want output like

```
 emp id   areaid   email_addr 
   1       1        aaaa@gmail.com,bbbb@gmail.com
   2       2        bbbb@gmail.com,eeee@gmail.com
   3       3        cccc@gmail.com
```

Comment: Looks like you'd join the Device table to the Users table.  Why is that not working for you?

Comment: i tried that also but i'm not sure i am crct. it get all email addres in single column for all

Comment: Do not include ",ss.email_addr" in the group by

Comment: @Piotr if i remove email_addr from group by means show error

Comment: I don't see any attempt in your code to join USERS to other USERS with the same `area`.   Why not?   You're using STUFF correctly, but your FROM clause is all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Outer query and group by should include only emp id,areaid.
Sub-query should create concatenate emails for single row.

Try:

```
   SELECT u.emp_id, u.areaid,
   stuff ((SELECT ', ' + ss.email_addr
   FROM  employee SS WHERE u.emp_id=ss.emp_id
   FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') email
   FROM users u 
   where u.ishod=1
   GROUP  BY u.emp_id,u.areaid
```

If you have SQL Server 2017, use String_agg instead of Stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the `emp_id` column in your expected output. So, I suppose you want lowest `emp_id` under same area. Also, I guess you mistakenly written 1st row of `email_addr` column of your expected output as `aaaa@gmail.com,bbbb@gmail.com` instead of `aaaa@gmail.com, dddd@gmail.com`.

If the above assumption is **OK**, then I think you can achieve your expected result using the following query.

```
SELECT
  MIN(u.emp_id) AS emp_id,
  u.areaid,
  STUFF(
   (
    SELECT ', ' + em.email_addr
    FROM  employee em 
    INNER JOIN USERS us ON  em.emp_id = us.emp_id
    WHERE us.areaid = u.areaid
    FOR XML PATH('')
   ),1,1,''
  ) AS email
FROM users u
GROUP  BY u.areaid
```

BUT....
As there is no employee in your given table for `emp_id` = 6, you can discard rows with empty email address by simply modifying the above query as follows

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT
    MIN(u.emp_id) AS emp_id,
    u.areaid,
    STUFF(
     (
      SELECT ', ' + em.email_addr
      FROM  employee em 
      INNER JOIN USERS us ON  em.emp_id = us.emp_id
      WHERE us.areaid = u.areaid
      FOR XML PATH('')
     ),1,1,''
    ) AS email
  FROM users u
  GROUP  BY u.areaid
) AS T
WHERE T.email IS NOT NULL
```

[Here is the working dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=29657c356804b14a7937bb37ecd99f14)

Hope, this helps. Thanks!